# What are the different endings, and how to reach them?

Tags: the-sexy-brutale

Finished The Sexy Brutale yesterday, but this morning I see a video talking about the ending I got being the 'Good Ending'

So what are the different endings, and how do I get them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two endings to the game, as far as I can tell. The good ending is the default ending, the bad ending requires getting all 52 cards and delivering them to the demon in the room of old habits.